# How can I find the price of an app on the iTunes app store using PHP?

Tags: php, web-crawler

I am going to be creating a website which will require up-to-date prices on certain iPhone apps, which I know is possible because the website AppShopper does just that except they do it with every website.  I am not that skilled using PHP though I am a quick learner.

I think that I will need to create a spider/**scraper** that takes the values from the website though I have done lots of research and I haven't figured it out, though I this may not be what I need.  I am not familiar with the creation of spiders, though I am willing to learn.  This will not be the key-point of the site so it doesn't need to be the most robust system, I would just like to be able to have it updated the prices

I would appreciate any help or suggestions that anyone has to offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an official Search API provided by Apple.  I haven't used it myself, but it's worth looking into.  Read more [here](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html).

Comment: This is a great help, thank you very much.  I am not sure why I didn't look at the Apple site first.